# How is the wattage of electrical appliance specified?

Tags: electricity, power

What does it mean by a bulb is 60 Watt or 100 watt (I know it means it emits 60 or 100 Joules of energy per second, but at what conditions)? Which one glows brighter when connected in series?? What happens in parallel combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which one glows brighter when connected in series?? What happens in
>   parallel combination?

For simplicity, treat the two bulbs as resistors with resistances

$$R_{60} = \frac{(120\mathrm{VAC})^2}{60W} = 240 \Omega $$

$$R_{100} = \frac{(120\mathrm{VAC})^2}{100W} = 144 \Omega $$

In parallel, both bulbs have 120VAC across just as if they were connected individually so the 100W bulb will be brighter.

In series, both bulbs have the same *current* through thus, the most power is delivered to the largest resistance which means that the 60W bulb will be brighter.

Answer (score 1):

A 60 watt bulb uses 60 watts of power when connected to a 117 V AC source. The 100 watt bulb uses 100 watts of power. The resistance of the filament determines the power the bulb consumes.

When the bulbs are connected in parallel (the usual connection), the 100 watt bulb will be brighter.

When the bulbs are connected in series, I believe the 60 watt bulb will be brighter.

Comment: A minor nit-pick: **Nothing** uses power;  the bulbs use **energy** at a 60 watt or 100 watt rate...